# Cannot save session variable after Steam OpenID Login (Flask)

Tags: python, flask, openid, steam-web-api

Currently trying to save the logged in steam id from the OpenID url. I can recieve the Steam ID and print it to the screen but once I try and save it to a session variable it will not exist after the browser has been shut down.

I have tried using HTTPS and also tried redirecting the user to the url with the steam id and saving it inside that but have had no results. I have tried setting other session variables and they work perfectly after shut down of the browser and remain exisitng.

```
from flask import redirect, request, session, url_for, g
from json import dumps, loads
from urllib.parse import urlencode

def SteamLogin():
    OpenID_Parameters = {
        'openid.ns': "http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0",
        'openid.identity': "http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/identifier_select",
        'openid.claimed_id': "http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0/identifier_select",
        'openid.mode': 'checkid_setup',
        'openid.return_to': 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/authorize',
        'openid.realm': 'http://127.0.0.1:5000'
    }

    OpenID_Parameters_URL = urlencode(OpenID_Parameters)
    OpenID_URL = ('https://steamcommunity.com/openid/login' + "?" + OpenID_Parameters_URL)
    OpenID = {"OpenIDUrl" : OpenID_URL}
    return dumps(OpenID)

def AuthorizeData():
    Received_Steam_Info_JSON = loads(dumps(request.args))
    userID = Received_Steam_Info_JSON['openid.claimed_id']
    session['user'] = userID
    return redirect("http://localhost:3000/")
```

Before closing the browser the user session variable will print the steam id. After closing the browser and printing session['user] it will show None.

Comment: I recommend that you use HTTPS instead of HTTP, because many browsers will block/reject some of the OIDC cookies involved when sent over HTTP.